# Sum Up All the Columns for Row Until End of List In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list=[[a],[b]]
```

it should return

1.values sum of list[a]

2.perform some operation

3.and then go back to (1) and do sum of list[b]

I tried below code:

```
K=[[a],[b]]
for ind,ele in enumerate(k):
    d=ele
    print(d)
    for j in range(len(d)):
        tot=tot+d[j]
        count=count+1
        print(tot)
    Avg=tot/count
```

Problem with this is it is performing only once i,e sum(k[a])
Your inputs are much appreciated

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem correctly. Are you trying to get the total sum of the lists in list=[[a],[b]] ? in that case you could do `total = sum([sum(i) for i in list])`

Comment: *"Your inputs are much appreciated"* - *Your* input (i.e., an actual example input) would be even more appreciated. And its expexted output, too.

Comment: Per @superbrain, please supply values for a and b so that we can reproduce your results.  Also, your code will produce a syntax error as is since you aren't initializing `tot` and `count`.  Please add those initializations to your code even if they are trivial.  In short, we should be able to copy/paste your code into our IDEs and have the code reproduce the result you are seeing and asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of your code with just enough added to the top of it to allow it to run, along with a few extra print statements added to show the values that `Avg` takes on during execution (and one typo fixed...you were using both 'k' and 'K' for the name of the input list):

```
a = 23
b = 1234
count = 0
tot = 0

k=[[a],[b]]
for ind,ele in enumerate(k):
        # count = 0
        # tot = 0
        d=ele
        print(d)
        for j in range(len(d)):
            tot=tot+d[j]
            count=count+1
            print(tot)
        Avg=tot/count
        print("The average at this point is:", Avg)

print("The average of all values is:", Avg)
```

Result:

```
[23]
23
The average at this point is: 23.0
[1234]
1257
The average at this point is: 628.5
The average of all values is: 628.5
```

Result with initialization lines uncommented:

```
[23]
23
The average at this point is: 23.0
[1234]
1234
The average at this point is: 1234.0
The average of all values is: 1234.0
```

This code works fine.  It shows that your inner loop is executed twice, once per element in 'k/K'. Per your description, it seems like you want to isolate the sum of each sub-list so that the result of summing earlier lists does not affect `Avg` for the current list you are processing.  If that's the case, then you should initialize `tot` and `count` at the top of each iteration of your outer loop.  You can do that by uncommenting the two lines I provide above that set those values to `0` inside the outer loop.  If you do this, then you don't need to initialize these values at the top of the code.

So this shows your code working just fine.  Given what I've said, what is the problem you're having?